# Substract the value that is already having minus in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. My XML is coming  like this

---

```
<b>
    <a>4205.0</a>
    <d>-152.22</d>
  </b>
```

2. I have taken values like this

---

```
var a = parseInt($(element).find('a').text());
var d = parseInt($(element).find('d').text());
var c=a-d;
```

> I want to minus a and d (a-d) that is 4205-152=4053, but since d value
>   already having '-' it is showing c as NAN, how can i bring this to
>   4053

Comment: its showing NAN !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So what is `element`?

Comment: try `console.log(a,d)` to check if values are there.

Comment: @LEO  , its a selector , please see the syntax which i pasted here $('summary', this).each(function(index, element)

Comment: cakan : values are there, no issues in that

Comment: well, your code seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/Lzzgy5x1/ you should only change `c=a-d` into `c=a+d`.

Comment: summary is some id or class ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `var c = b - Math.abs(d)`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are trying to parse the value of tag `a` which contains two child nodes- `b` and `d` which contains actual values.  what you want to do is this

```
var a = parseInt($(element).find('b').text()); //change is here
//previously it was --->find('a').text()
var d = parseInt($(element).find('d').text());
var c=a-d;
```

just simple mistake can make a huge blunder :)